# How do I prevent an Angular method to fire more than once?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this Angular function that fires multiple times and I'm confused as to why it does this. On the backend, I have a console.log() statement that logs every time the endpoint is tapped. The statement fires 4 times. instagramService.tapInsta();
should only be called only once. Can someone tell me why and how this is happeneing?

---

```
'use strict';

console.log("OUTSIDE alloyController");

angular.module("mainModule")
    .controller('alloyController', function ($scope, instagramService) {

    console.log("INSIDE alloyController");

    $scope.windowInfoWithToken = instagramService.getWindowInfo();

    instagramService.tapInsta($scope.windowInfoWithToken, function (response) {

        $scope.instagramData = response.data;

        if (!response.data.access_token == undefined) {

            $scope.instagramDataWithToken = response.data.access_token;

        } else {

            $scope.hideThisDiv = true;
        }

        console.info(response.data);

    });

});
```

---

In reply to a comment, I have the actual API call done in a service:

```
'use strict';

console.log("OUTSIDE dataService");

angular.module("mainModule")
    .service('instagramService', function ($http) {

    console.log("INSIDE dataService");

    this.tapInsta = function (access_token, callback) {

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/ig',
            data: {
                token: access_token
            }
        })

        .then(callback);
    }

    this.tapInstaExtended = function (access_token, instaQuery, callback) {

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/instaInputQuery',
            data: {
                token: access_token,
                query: instaQuery
            }
        })

        .then(callback);
    }

    this.getHandleAuth = function (callback) {


        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/handleauth',
            data: {
                name: "LTQ"
            }
        })

        .then(callback);

    }

    this.getWindowInfo = function () {

        var windowLocation = window.location.href;

        if (windowLocation.indexOf("losethequit") != -1) {
            var windowLocationWithToken = windowLocation.replace("https://losethequit.herokuapp.com/views/werkspayce.html?code=", "");
        } else {
            var windowLocationWithToken = windowLocation.replace("http://localhost:5000/views/werkspayce.html?code=", "");
        }

        return windowLocationWithToken;

    };

});
```

---

Comment: How many times is this controller used on the page?

Answer (score 2):

Insert a `debugger;` into the body of the function, open (recommended in chrome) "Developer tools" (simply inspect a element) and check "Call stack", so you see what function are calling it.

Comment: (anonymous function) (alloyController.js:141)
(anonymous function) (angular.js:15961)
n.$eval (angular.js:17229)
n.$digest (angular.js:17045)
n.$apply (angular.js:17337)
l (angular.js:11572)
H (angular.js:11778)
u.onload (angular.js:11711)

Comment: @LTQ so you should click on each function and you'll se the code that is calling it

Comment: there's one anonymous function - the actual function itself. The others are angular calls. like n.$eval and n.$digest and n.$apply   ---- it seems as if angular is making these multiple calls.

Comment: @LTQ sorry but its kinda difficult to help you if I cant see it, so you have to figure it out on your own

Answer (score 1):

How many instances of this are on the page? I believe Angular will have a controller for each instance which can cause this API call to occur multiple times. Generally you'll be better off placing API calls within a service (service, factory or provider, take your pick) which will be a singleton within the app.

Comment: There's only one call to the controller on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't showing it, but are you using routing? If so, are you calling your controller in your routing template AND in your markup/view? If so, this can cause all functions to trigger twice.

You only need to call to the controller in your routing.

Comment: @chrstianhill I'm sorry - yes I'm yes express four routing. I'm not using a routing template, my controller is only called in one html file - this one html file holds multiple directives.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your help. It seems as if using the same controller for multiple directives calls functions in the controller multiple. So, if you're using the controller in 3 different directives - any statements called directly from a service, as opposed to being nested in a $scope function, will be called 3 times. Just FYI.

---

```
   'use strict';

    console.log("OUTSIDE instagramDirective");

    angular.module("mainModule")
    .directive('instagram', function () {

    console.log("INSIDE instagramDirective");

    return {
        templateUrl: '/templates/instagram.html',
        controller: 'instagramController',
        replace: false
    }

});
```